# Drag force equals weight

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

we are doing lab in mechanics class.The task is find terminal velocity of drop of coffee filter and drag force 's constant $B$ in graphically  as  equation like $mg = Bv^2$ 
so basically drag force equals weight than first law of newton says there is constant velocity .no acceleration at all. so equation of big 5 like $x=v0t+(1/2)gt^2$ doesnt work. the only thing to do is to use  $mg = Bv^2$ solve for $

b$ constant is to find mass and velocity and for velocity distance and time

we need to notice mass of matter affects velocity when we consider air resistance
Am I right or wrong at anything?
and I thought mg at y axis and v^2 at x axis directly proportional so slope will give me constant value .

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the mass of the droplet $m$ should be constant. So if you plot $mg$, ,which is also a constant (independent of $v$), on y-axis, your graph is simply a horizontal line.

Comment: can't understand your question. do you want to find terminal velocity as a function of (mg, B) or what

Answer (score 0):

taking downward direction as positive :

$mg-Bv^2=ma =mv\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$ \implies v\dfrac{dv}{dt}=g-\dfrac{Bv^2}{m}$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{v}\dfrac{vdv}{g-\dfrac{Bv^2}{m}}=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}dt$

$\left(1-\dfrac{Bv^2}{mg} \right)=e^{\dfrac{-2Bt}{m}}$

$\implies v(t)=\sqrt{\dfrac{mg}{B}}\left(1-e^{\dfrac{-2Bt}{m}}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{2}}\tag{1}$

this is the velcoity of body at any time t (it is not constant but is varying with time)

and the force equation which you've written(drag force = weight)  is valid only when body reaches in equillibrium (i.e, when $t\to \infty$ and $v=v_{t}$ =terminal velocity) after very long time

$mg-Bv^2=0\implies v=v_{t}=\sqrt{\dfrac{mg}{B}}$

the terminal velocity can also be found from eq. (1)  by setting $t\to\infty$

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are finding the terminal velocity of your system as a function of weight so the gradient of your graph of weight against velocity squared should be the constant $b$ provided that $b$ is indeed constant ie changing the weight does not alter the aerodynamics of your system.